# Line Chart: background of RangeSlider

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, kendo-dataviz, chart.js

I want to develop a range slider like same as it is shown at http://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-chart-with-scroll-and-zoom/#theme-light

Basically the idea is to develop a chart and add a range slider. is there any idea that how i can set the chart as background of range slider?

Thanks,

Comment: You mean like this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367?

Comment: yes please. I am using kendo ui and have no issue with any other javascript library.

Comment: but using json not csv data

Comment: I won't and I doubt anyone else is going to do the work for you.  Take a crack at it and come back with the **specific** problems...

Comment: bro i am going byself :-S, i have copy pasted code mentioned below, and its working fine. 
Issue is, it has no rangeslider, but when i click and move mouse, then it shows the area which is selected.

Comment: my requirement is rangeslider with background as same graph

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aqdasiftekhar/L41p61w9/8/
Please have a look at this. I need to get selected value from data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background is already the same chart in the rangeslider.

You cannot logically move the range slider into main area - where would you drag the slider to?

However, if you are just looking to select a moving window (say as a filter), you can do it by resizing the chartScrollbar to fill the height of the chart (leaving a bit so that it doesn't get clipped off)

```
"scrollbarHeight": 490
```

and the hiding the actual chart's components (points, lines, axes, tooltips) using CSS so that they don't interfere.

```
#chartdiv svg > g:nth-child(<<index of layer to hide>>) {
  display: none;
}
```

If you want the axes, identify the chart layer with the axes and set it's transform to translate(0, 0) so that it overlaps the scrollbarChart.

---

CodePen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waYzpw

---

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aqdasiftekhar/L41p61w9/8/

Please have a look at this. I need to get selected value from data

Comment: it's available in brushed() - `console.log(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());`

Comment: wow, great Thanks for helping me bro.  i wish i could give you one more vote :-)

Comment: based on link http://jsfiddle.net/aqdasiftekhar/L41p61w9/8/, is it possible that it shows only date/week/month and year but not time if there is very small data. i.e. 2 dates only?